# Webmaster Tools and Google differ on "robots.txt"

Tags: google-search-console

I'm getting a tad tired of Webmaster Tools and its inability to agree with itself.

I'm seeing a warning that there are 'Sever health issues' with my domain.

Checking this Google seems CONVINCED that my robots.txt file is blocking my sitemap, even though Webmaster Tools itself says that my robots.txt file is AOK (and it is).

Looking at my sitemap I'm getting an error: "URL restricted by robots.txt".

Ok then.

I've tried deleting the sitemap from Google and re-adding it, no luck. I've tried doing the same with the robots.txt file, no luck. It;s convinced that my robots file is blocking the sitemap.

The funniest thing is that the www. version of the same domain is reporting that everything is fine. *It's the same website*.

So is Webmaster Tools just fundamentally broken, and I should ignore it, or is it flagging something I should be delving deeper into? Is the domain likely to be punished if Google itself thinks it can't see the sitemap (even though it can)?

Domains live and die by Googles hands, so I feel a tad frustrated that it's so insolent.

Edited to add:

I've just tried an experiment. Completely removing my functional `Allow: /` robots file seemed to get it to work. The file's cache life was an hour, and it's checked it several times over the past few days. Definitely bugged.

Comment: It seems to me that this subject would fit better in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe. That's probably a topic for whichstackdoineedtousenow.stackexchange.com. But I don't have enough rep to reply to comments there ;) (seriously, I'm surprised they don't have a separate exchange for questions involving the colour blue)